# Textfield List and field.Choices issue

Tags: django, list, loops

I have an issue when my IP list from a text field goes into "ip_list_coices", instead of having each IP as a choice on one line.

The IPs need to be separate choices. I have a feeling this might be an easy fix, but can't seem to figure it out.

*Below are examples*:

**This is what happens:**

192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3 ... 192.168.1.5

**This is what I wish for:**

192.168.1.2

192.168.1.3

...

192.168.1.5

**models.py**

> ```
> #IP Block Class
> class IP_block(models.Model):
>
> #ip block and range save function
>
>
> def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
>
>     slash = unicode(self.slash)
>
>     self.broadcast_ip = broadcast
>     self.subnet = subnet
>
>
>     #rangeip for loop
>
>     ip = IP(self.network + slash)
>
>
>     for rangeip in ip[2:-1]:
>         self.ip_range += "%s \n" %rangeip
>
>     super(IP_block, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
>
>
> network = models.IPAddressField(unique=True)
> slash = models.ForeignKey(Subnet, verbose_name='CIDR')
> subnet = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
> gateway_ip = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
> broadcast_ip = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
> ip_range = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Available IP Range')
> dslam = models.ManyToManyField(Dslam, verbose_name='Dslam', blank=True)
> ip_list = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
>
> class Meta:
>     verbose_name_plural = 'IP Blocks'
>
> def __unicode__(self):
>     return self.network
> ```

**forms.py as recommended by Daniel**

> ```
> class IP_blockForm(forms.ModelForm):
>     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>     super(IP_blockForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>         if self.instance and self.instance.ip_range:
>
>             #This is where I pass the list from the text field    
>
>             ip_list_choices = [(self.instance.ip_range, self.instance.ip_range ),]
>
>             self.fields['ip_list'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ip_list_choices)
>
>     class Meta:
>         model = IP_block
> ```

Comment: You're retrieving ip_range (which is a single TextField) from a single instance. I don't understand quite well what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok, instead of saving the list of IP Addresses from the for loop into a textfield. Can I pass the list of IP Addresses directly for my choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
split_range = self.instance.ip_range.split(' ') #Or whatever your delimiter is
ip_list_choices = zip(split_range, split_range) #Gives you a tuple. 
self.fields['ip_list'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ip_list_choices)
```

Comment: This worked!!! Thanks for the all help again. That was such a basic fix like the other time.